# Action bar below a tab view

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I want to create a TabView like in this example: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Below it I'd like an action bar with buttons that should always appear on the bottom of the screen. How ever. When i place another LinearLayout with vertical orientation to the TabHost it disappears beyond the screen limits. Here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />

        <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false">

            <Button android:text="Add" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
            <ToggleButton android:text="Aus" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Edit: Added my xml code

Comment: You need to add your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that layout definition, something's gotta give.  Currently, both the `FrameLayout` for the tab contents and the `LinearLayout` below it are asking to fill the remaining height of the screen with `android:layout_height="fill_parent".

In order to do what you are expecting, you need to define the "action bar" `LinearLayout` to wrap its contents vertically, and tell the `FrameLayout` simply to fill the available space between the tabs and that bottom bar.  We do this by adding a weight parameter.  I've modified your inner layout below with these two things:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:padding="5dp">

  <TabWidget
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <FrameLayout
    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <Button android:text="Add"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
    <ToggleButton android:text="Aus"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope that Helps!

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to surround your 'action bar' and other linear layout inside another linear layout.

So you tab has a linear layout for it's content.
In that linear layout you have linear layout for the real content.
Then you have your action bar.

Psuedo code:

```
<LinearLayout...>
    <LinearLayout...>
        <!-- Views here for the content of the tab -->
    </LinearLayout>
    <MyActionBarView...>
    </MyActionBarView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by searching for the keyword bottom in within the android-layout tag. The answer is Relative Layout. Here is the functioning xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

            <Button android:text="Add" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />
            <ToggleButton android:text="Aus" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dp" android:layout_below="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```